# ios objective c parsing json

Tags: ios, json

Trying to parse this json and cannot seem to figure it out.

> {
>           description = "Description Variant 1 ";
>           id = 4;
>           price = "25.0";
>       },
>           {
>           description = "Variant 2 Description ";
>           id = 5;
>           price = "50.0";
>       },
>           {
>           description = "Variant 3 Description";
>           id = 6;
>           price = "75.0";
>       }

Here is my code, but I get a SigAbt on the NSLog:

```
- (NSMutableArray *) getVariants:(NSString *)variantJson 
{
    NSMutableArray *variants = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    NSLog(@"Variant JSON: %@", variantJson);

    NSArray *vars = [variantJson valueForKeyPath:@"variants"];

    for (id var in vars) 
    {
        NSLog(@"description: %@",[var objectForKey:@"description"]);

    }

    return variants;
}
```

The json coming in to variable:  variantJson is the above posted JSON.

Comment: The JSON string you posted is not valid. You can check the validity of your JSON at http://jsonlint.com. Check the other answers for info on how to parse it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

iOS doesn't parse JSON this transparently; you need to run your string through an actual JSON parser library, like [SBJson](https://github.com/stig/json-framework). (BSD-licensed) Or you can use the built-in [NSJSONSerialization](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSJSONSerialization_Class/Reference/Reference.html) if you're targeting OS 5 or later.

Answer (score 1):

You have no code for parsing the JSON there. Objective-C and Cocoa have not built-in mechanism for automagically parsing JSON string into objects and dictionaries and `valueForKeyPath` is for getting property value (within hierarchy) of KVC-compliant objective-c classes.

In order to get nested `NSDictionary`'ies and `NSArray`'s you need to employ some third party library or write your own code.
Take a look at the list of libraries at [JSON page](http://www.json.org/).