# Top level JSON object attributes Objective-c

Tags: objective-c, ios, json

How can I access high level JSON object in Objective-c? Here's the JSON

```
{
  user: "user",
  id: 39,
  image: "img.png",
  caption: "",
  lat: "37",
  lng: "-122",
  created_at: 1356910240
}
```

... and I need to do something like this [JSON valueFor???:????]

I can add object "identifier" and access it like [JSON valueForKeyPath:@"identifier"] but wondering if there is another way?

```
identifier: {
  user: "user",
  id: 39,
  image: "img.png",
  caption: "",
  lat: "37",
  lng: "-122",
  created_at: 1356910240
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: what are you using for parsing? Usually the object returned by the JSON parses is a `NSDictionary` representing the top level JSON object.

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8407577/ios-objective-c-parsing-json.

Comment: I have a custom parser, just need a way to access JSON object without using 'valueForKeyPath'.

Comment: @AndreiTaraschuk How are _we_ supposed to tell you how to use _your_ custom parser?

Comment: @AlexWayne - let me rephrase, all I need to do is access a JSON object without a key (first option in the above example). When then key is present I can simply use valueForKeyPath. Also, I am using AFNetworking plugin to load JSON.

Comment: @AndreiTaraschuk  The root node _is_ the object you are querying. Assuming you are doing parsing in a way that is sane, the object you want is the very object you would call `valueForKeyPath:` on. This is why everyone is so confused about what you are after.

Comment: Your latter rendition, with the `identifier`, is not valid JSON. You would need to wrap that in an additional set of braces, if you wanted to do that. But that doesn't buy you anything, anyway. Alex Wayne's answer represents the right way to extract data from your first rendition, with no additional dictionary with a single key, `identifier`, needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typically, a JSON parser will return a dictionary/hash/associative array, whatever the language being used uses for key/value pairs.

In ObjectiveC, that would be `NSDictionary`.  So your parser should be doing this:

```
NSDictionary *data = [SomeJSONParser decodeJson:jsonString];
```

Now to get `"user"` from that we would do:

```
[data objectForKey:@"user"];
```

But you want the root node? Well you *already have it.* The root node is the dictionary your parser spits out. There is no magic method to call, the root node is simply the result of the parser.

If your "custom parser" works differently, I would suggest you change it.  Making this do what you want is entirely dependent on the API of your parser and what types of objects it returns, both things you left incredibly vague in your question.

Comment: Alex, you are awesome! For some reason I didn't try accessing root node directly! Thanks a bunch!